# Conditional rendering based on state

Tags: reactjs

I want to do some conditional rendering based on what is in state. My state looks something along the lines of this:

```
state = {
  text: '',
  properties: {
     someMoreData: [{...}]
  },
  moreData: ''
}
```

I want to do conditional rendering based on whether or not the `someMoreData` field exists within the properties key in my state. My current code looks like this:

```
render () {
     console.log(this.state)
     if('someMoreData' in this.state.properties)
     return (
         <div>
          ..
         </div>
     )
}
```

React is throwing an error stating `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'someMoreData' in undefined`

How to can i format my code so that if the `someMoreData` field exists, I get my JSX, and if not i render some other JSX.

Comment: That's not really how the `in` operator works nor how it is used in JavaScript.  If you simply need to know whether or not `someMoreData` is not falsy, you can do `if (this.state.properties.someMoreData) { ... some code ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you just do something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.properties.someMoreData && (
          <div>Some other JSX stuff</div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'someMoreData' in undefined` seems to indicate that for whatever reason `this.state.properties` is `undefined`. Not sure why with only the code you've posted, but I would look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ternary operators

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.properties.someMoreData ? 
          // someMoreData exists
          (<div>Some JSX stuff</div>) 
          :
          //someMoreData does not exist
          (<div>Some other JSX stuff</div>)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```